# Enable demographics in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

My blogger website is linked to google analytics. Now I want to get demographics data I have enabled it in the settings but still, it is not giving any data about demographics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to wait a few days, or longer; particularly if your site has a low volume of sessions per day. Google will not show you the data below a certain threshold as this becomes to close to revealing individuals by, for example, age, gender and location. 
[Read more here,](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en) particularly on data thresholds.